# Cat Content after a specific line in log file

Tags: unix, cat

I would like to cat the contents of a file that follows and includes the target line.

```
2014-06-23 11:01:01,001 dog  
2014-06-23 12:01:01,001 cat  
2014-06-23 13:01:01,001 elephant    
2014-06-23 14:01:01,001 bird  
2014-06-23 15:01:01,001 rabbit  
2014-06-23 16:01:01,001 deer
```

I want to cat the line *2014-06-23 13:01:01,001 elephant* and following lines by searching *2014-06-23 13:01:01,001*

The desired output would be:

```
2014-06-23 13:01:01,001 elephant    
2014-06-23 14:01:01,001 bird  
2014-06-23 15:01:01,001 rabbit  
2014-06-23 16:01:01,001 deer
```

Thank you in advance and I always welcome documentation links!

Comment: `tail` and `grep` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can print from the pattern `2014-06-23 13:01:01,001` to the end of the file, like this:

```
$ sed -n '/2014-06-23 13:01:01,001/,$p' file
2014-06-23 13:01:01,001 elephant
2014-06-23 14:01:01,001 bird
2014-06-23 15:01:01,001 rabbit
2014-06-23 16:01:01,001 deer
```

Comment: *It worked on my machine* That was a typo, but I agree that I'll need to pass the variable to awk. Your solution is much more elegant. +1.